# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

There is a pivot view in my module.Earlier it works fine.But now when i click on the + sign it shows the error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not easy to debug. You have to debug in the browser console (developer tools) to get a hint, what is wrong on server side. Until that, almost no one can help you out :-(

Comment: Sometimes Odoo error logging is so enlightening. Sorry, can't stop this sarcastic move. I have seen this error so often. The error description is just so unspecific, I can't remember the solution